# how to make condition in ajax with date if null not display default format 1970/01/01?

Tags: javascript, ajax

i just want to if the data date null from my database not showing the default.

```
.done(function(dt) {
            if (dt != null) {
                console.log(dt)
                table.rows().remove().draw();
                $.each(dt, function(i, item) {
                    var d = new Date(item.date);
                    var day = d.getDate();
                    var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
                    var year = d.getFullYear();

                    var d_date= day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
                    
                    table.row.add([
                        item.Name,
                        d_date,
                        item.Attendance,
                        "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info' onclick='showDetail(" + item.NIK + ");' >Detail</button>"
                    ]).draw();
                })
            }
        })
```

and its the result.

[image]

Comment: You are comparing if the data is not null , you wanna make an else or give us more informations .

Comment: i just want to make the date if null, displaying nothing but not the dafault date like 01/01/1970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add an if condition:

```
.done(function(dt) {
    if (dt != null) {
        console.log(dt)
        table.rows().remove().draw();
        $.each(dt, function(i, item) {
            var d = ""
            var day = ""
            var month = ""
            var year = ""
            var d_date= ""

            if (item.date) {
                d = new Date(item.date);
                day = d.getDate();
                month = d.getMonth() + 1;
                year = d.getFullYear();

                d_date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            }
            
            table.row.add([
                item.Name,
                d_date,
                item.Attendance,
                "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info' onclick='showDetail(" + item.NIK + ");' >Detail</button>"
            ]).draw();
        })
    }
})
```